# Doctrine 1.2/Symfony 1.4 not generating proper foreign-key relationships?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I've inherited a Symfony 1.4/Doctrine 1.2 application that I have to maintain.  I am trying to make some changes to the schema.yml file and generate new models and sql defns from it, but for some reason, my foreign key relationships are not being generated completely.

I presume that I am likely missing something obvious in the schema.yml file, but it isn't popping out at me:

I've edited the schema.yml file down to some basics:

```
SCHEMA.YML:
connection: doctrine
options:
  type: innodb
  charset: utf8

MasterIndex:
  tableName: master_index
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    last_name:
      type: string(255)
      notnull: true
    first_name:
      type: string(255)
      notnull: true

Poem:
  tableName: poem
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    user_id: string(50)
    title: string(250)
    pen_name: string(250)
    contents: string()
    invoice_id: integer
  relations:
    Invoice:
      local: invoice_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: poems
      foreignType: many
      type: one
    MasterIndex:
      local: user_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: poems
      foreignType: one
      type: many

Invoice:
  tableName: invoice
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    user_id:
      type: string(50)
      notnull: true
    amount:
      type: float()
      notnull: true
```

After running a symfony doctrine:clean doctrine:build-model and doctrine:build-sql, I get the following schema.sql generated:

```
CREATE TABLE invoice (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, user_id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, amount FLOAT(18, 2) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE = innodb;
CREATE TABLE master_index (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE = innodb;
CREATE TABLE poem (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, user_id VARCHAR(50), title VARCHAR(250), pen_name VARCHAR(250), contents TEXT, invoice_id BIGINT, INDEX invoice_id_idx (invoice_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE = innodb;
ALTER TABLE poem ADD CONSTRAINT poem_invoice_id_invoice_id FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id) REFERENCES invoice(id);
```

I'm expecting 2 foreign key constraint in the poem table - invoice_id to the Invoice table and user_id to the MasterIndex table, but only one contraint appears!  I am missing my foreign key constraint in the poem table to the master_index table.

Am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: `user_id: type: string(50)` should be `user_id: type: integer`. Foreign keys must match the type of the referenced column.

Comment: @1ed Can't believe I didn't see that.  Also noticed that I had foreignType and Type mixed up (ie: type should be one, and foreignType many).  Works as expected now - thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foreign keys must match the type of the referenced column:

`user_id: type: string(50)` should be `user_id: type: integer`.